# How is possible to use participles gramatically after verbs such as "want" or "would like"?

Tags: grammar

I see the uses of them in the following sentences in some articles:

> What are the questions you want answered before you die?
>
> Do you have any questions that you would like answered?

Comment: I'm not sure those are participles.  A participle is when a verb functions adjectivally; in both your examples, "answered" seems to be nominal (as an infinitive passive verbal noun, short for "to be answered").

Comment: Thank you so much. That's the answer of my question. I had not understood the uses of the examples included in my question until I saw your answer. But now I know that these are short form of "to be answered" :)

Comment: @KurtWeber They are not a short form of "to be answered". "Answered" is past participle verb serving as head of the complement clauses "answered before you die" and "answered". By no means all participles can function as adjectives; in fact most can't.

Comment: The second sentence should read *have* ***you***.

Comment: Whether it should be "do you have" or "have you" depends on how you view the verb "have" here. Most speakers treat it as a lexical verb, in which case _do_-support is required. For those who take it as an auxiliary verb, then "do" is not required. Compare "Does he have enough money?" (lexical "have") vs "Has he enough money?" (auxiliary "have).

Answer (score 1):

> *What are the questions you want [answered before you die]?*
>
> *Have any questions that you would like [answered]?*

"Want" and "like" are catenative verbs and these are both catenative constructions.

The bracketed elements are past participial clauses functioning as catenative complements of "want" and "like".

The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for "chain", which is appropriate here since "want answered" and "like answered" are chains of verbs.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on your question, but in the case of actual participles, it's pretty straightforward how it's possible.

Since a participle is a verbal adjective, it can be used anywhere an adjective can be used.  Since an adjective modifies a noun, it can accompany any noun, including a noun that is the direct object of a transitive verb.  So if you say "I want a dog," then you can say both "I want a green dog" ("green" here is a normal adjective) and "I want a running dog") ("running" being a participle).